# atomic_cas32 in boost interprocess library

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

What does the following lines of code does ?

```
boost::interprocess::detail::atomic_cas32( &m_shutdown, 1, 1 ) == 1
```

According to the documentation, it does the following thing

//! Compare an boost::uint32_t's value with "cmp".
//! If they are the same swap the value with "with"
//! "mem": pointer to the value
//! "with": what to swap it with
//! "cmp": the value to compare it to
//! Returns the old value of *mem

Can somebody tell me what this atomic_cas32 does ?

Comment: what part are you confused about? WP might help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap

Comment: that wikipedia link is helpful